# How to pass the "Key To Her Heart" mission (Hot Coffee mod)?

Tags: mods, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

In *GTA: San Andreas*, I see several people are having problems passing the "Key To Her Heart" mission (Hot Coffee mod):

- [A Key To Her Heart - Hot Coffee Mod](https://gtaforums.com/topic/231843-a-key-to-her-heart-hot-coffee-mod/)
- [key to her heart](https://gtaforums.com/topic/430351-key-to-her-heart/)
- [[SNP] Key To Her Heart - Hot Coffee modded](https://gtaforums.com/topic/212851-snp-key-to-her-heart-hot-coffee-modded/)

I can't spank the girl (Millie) hard enough to pass the mission. Some say turn on the Frame Limiter but I have tried more than 2 times and I still can't pass it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mission is not hard like you think it is, just concentrate and hit the key (Space bar key if you use default control settings) when the Power bar is full...

But of course, in PC, there is other way to pass this mission: just set the Excitement bar to full with Cheat Engine.

Step 1: Progress the mission to the part where you enter the girl's house, and you start to spank, pause right there.

Step 2: Use Alt + Tab to switch to desktop and open Cheat Engine.

Step 3: I assume you know how to use Cheat Engine, the memory address of the girl's excitement is `gta_sa.exe+64AC64`, data type is `Float`. Now you can control the girl's excitement with Cheat Engine.

Step 4: Set & Freeze the girl's excitement to `100` via Cheat Engine.

Step 5: Back to the game and spank the girl 1 spank (since you have freezed the girl's excitement, so the excitement won't drop, you can slowly concentrate and hit the key when the Power bar is full) and you pass the mission.